# TypeScript custom definition file

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

So i have a third party library with global functions available like jQuery: $.functionName() but no definition file. So i wanted to write my own file but i cant make the reference/import working.

If i write my declarations inline it works fine:

```
declare let a:string;

myClass {
   constructor() {
       console.log(a);
   }
}
```

But if i declare it in another file i cant make it work:

*myDeclaration.d.ts*

```
export declare let a:string;
```

*myClass.ts*

```
/// <reference path="myDeclaration.d.ts" />

myClass {
   constructor() {
       console.log(a);
   }
}
```

I also tried `import * as a from "myDeclaration"`. It always says: `Cannot find name 'a'`

Answer (score 0):

You should not use export with `ambient` declarations.

Just remove the export from you .d.ts, like this:

```
declare let a:string
```

Normally you can even remove the `<reference path="">` as the declaration should be available to your whole project.

You should use `export declare` when writing a definition for a module that is imported, a JS npm library for example, and use `ambient` definition when the object is available globally without any import (jQuery imported by `<script>` for example).